# Weekly Sales Sum by location ID

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sum, aggregate

I have this table:

```
locationid |Sales     |salesdate
:----------|:--------:|--------:
40         |571.00    |2007-01-01   
40         |1377.00   |2007-01-02
40         |571.00    |2007-01-01   
40         |1377.00   |2007-01-02
40         |571.00    |2007-01-01   
40         |1377.00   |2007-01-02
40         |571.00    |2007-01-01   
40         |1377.00   |2007-01-02
```

I Have about 200 unique location IDs and my question is how would I be able to sum 7 day sales by location ID?

My overall goal is get 7 day sales per location and 7 day last year sales per location.

Theoretically I would just take each date and sum date-7,I should have around 52-53 entries (depending on the year), however I'm not sure how to do this.

I poked around a bit and found this:

```
SELECT SUM(sales) as 'Total',
       SUM( CASE WHEN convert(varchar(11),salesdate,101) >= convert(varchar(11),GETDATE() - 7,101)  
                 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) as 'Current',
       SUM( CASE WHEN convert(varchar(11),salesdate,101) >= convert(varchar(11),GETDATE() - 14,101)  
                 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) as '7Days' ,
       SUM( CASE WHEN convert(varchar(11),salesdate,101) >= convert(varchar(11),GETDATE() - 28,101)  
                 THEN sales ELSE 0 END) as '14Days' 
FROM [MYSQL].[wfmsales].[sales_bk]
```

However that only does a total sum and doesn't sum per location and i haven't figured that part out yet. Thank you very much in advance for your time. This is my first post on stackoverflow, so if i did anything wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the date functions for date arithmetic.  I'm not sure what output you want, but for the last 7 days, you can do:

```
SELECT locationId, SUM(sales) as sales_Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN salesdate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAYS THEN sales ELSE 0 END) as sales_Current
FROM [MYSQL].[wfmsales].[sales_bk]
GROUP BY locationId;
```

You can add additional `SUM(CASE)` expressions for any period of time you would like.

Comment: Thank Gordon, the time component for me is irrelevant. I'll go ahead and test this out!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `SUM(CASE WHEN...)` queries are working as you expect, you need to `GROUP BY` the locationId column.

```
SELECT locationId, SUM(sales) as 'Total',
           SUM( CASE WHEN convert(varchar(11),salesdate,101) >= convert(varchar(11),GETDATE() - 7,101)  
                     THEN sales ELSE 0 END) as 'Current',
           SUM( CASE WHEN convert(varchar(11),salesdate,101) >= convert(varchar(11),GETDATE() - 14,101)  
                     THEN sales ELSE 0 END) as '7Days' ,
           SUM( CASE WHEN convert(varchar(11),salesdate,101) >= convert(varchar(11),GETDATE() - 28,101)  
                     THEN sales ELSE 0 END) as '14Days' 
    FROM [MYSQL].[wfmsales].[sales_bk]
    GROUP By locationId
```